# 2D markings vs 3D objects: How to optimize re-localizing with ADF using Google Tango?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I’m trying to create a simple AR simulation in Unity, and I want to speed up the process of re-localizing based on the ADF after I lose tracking in game. For example, is it better to have landmarks that are 3D shapes in the environment that are unchanging, or is it better to have landmarks that are 2D markings?

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be one of these two, I would say 2D marking (visual features) would be preferred. So first, Tango is not using depth sensor for relocalization or pose estimations, 3D geometry is not necessary helping on the tracking. In a extremely case, if the device is in a pure white environment (with no shadows) with lots of boxes in it, it will still lost tracking eventually, because there's no visual features being tracking.

On the other hand, if there's a empty room, with lots of poster in it. Even it's not that "interesting" from its geometry. But it is good for tracking because it has enough visual feature to tracking.

Comment: If the room is very large & empty; would it be enough to poster the floor and walls or would there need to be visual markers suspended through out the empty space?

Also does the size of the space, and thus the ADFfile, have a limit that might impact performance during relocalization? ideally want to avoid having to slice up the room into several ADFfiles and just treat it as one large space.

If i created an area in the room that has a particularly dense amount of posters or visual material for the tango to latch onto, could i reliably come back to this area of the room to relocalize?

Answer (score 1):

Motion tracking API of Tango uses MonoSLAM algorithm. It uses wideangle camera and motion sensors to estimate pose of device. It doesn't use depth information into consideration to estimate pose vector of device.

In general SLAM algorithms uses feature detectors like Harris corner detection, FAST feature detection to detect features and track them. So it's better to put up 2D markers with rich of features like say any random pattern or any painting. This will help in feature tracking in case of MonoSLAM and generating rich ADF. Putting up 2D patterns at different places and at different 3D levels will even improve tracking of project tango.